# Conditional Sumif formula is adding numbers outside of range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have column U, which should be summing only values with a unique index. So for the highlighted cell, it should only add column T if column A in the same. I can't tell what is wrong with my formula, it is pulling numbers from a different source in the workbook.

My formula:
`=if(A3168<>A3169,sumif($A$2:A3168,A3168,$T$2:T3168),"")`

[image: Example of formula and output]

Any help with this very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means the value in column A is found further up the sheet. 204 exists in earlier rows.

to truly do just the grouping put this in U2:

```
=IF(A2<>A3,SUM($T$2:$T2)-SUM($U$1:$U1),"")
```

And copy down.